# Fill Dropdown for Timer control while page editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, dropdown

I have 4 DropDowns for Timer control. And I use one for hours (12 hr format), one for minutes, one for seconds and one for AM/PM. And I fill 3 (Hours, min, sec) with below code:

```
public void fillhrs()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        ddlhour.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }
    ddlmin.Items.Add("00");
    for (int j = 1; j <= 59; j++)
    {
        ddlmin.Items.Add(new ListItem(j.ToString(), j.ToString()));
    }
    ddlsec.Items.Add("00");
    for (int k = 1; k <= 59; k++)
    {
        ddlsec.Items.Add(new ListItem(k.ToString(), k.ToString()));
    }
}
```

In my database it should save like "13:26:00"

Now my question is, if I want to edit the the page, how can I fill the DropDowns with above time -13:26:00 that means when I was enter the time 13 hr should be taken as 1 and pm. So how can I bind DropDowns with 13 as 1 pm?

Comment: What are `ddlhour` et.al., and their `Items`?  What does the documentation say for those classes?

Comment: have you tried g:i a gets the time and turns into am and pm